# How do i archive multiple folders using python?

Tags: python, minecraft, zip

I am trying to zip 3 folders: named World, World_nether, World_the_end
into 1 zip file, I could only get only one folder to zip :

```
import shutil
import zipfile

shutil.make_archive("text", 'zip', "D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world ",)
```

all of the folders are in the same location/dir

```
D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world
D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world_nether
D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world_the_end
```

are the directories

Comment: Move them into the same folder first and then zip that folder.

Comment: i cannot do that since its a folder for a server and it just doesnt run if its not in the same directory

Comment: if .../world, .../world_, .../world_the_end are not in the same directory?

Comment: well i have them in one folder but the issue is it has other files in that folder too! but i dont want to save thosse files. It looks like this : [link](https://imgur.com/mXmjAVa)

Answer (score 3):

Try this the following code, it copies the required files into a separate directory and then zips that directory:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile("D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world", "D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\ZipFolder\world")
shutil.copyfile("D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world_nether", "D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\ZipFolder\world_nether")
shutil.copyfile("D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\world_the_end", "D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\ZipFolder\world_the_end")

shutil.make_archive("text", 'zip', "D:\Scripts\MCserver\Server\ZipFolder")
```

Comment: i changed some things to make it work had to use 'shutil.copytree((sys.path[0] + ("\Server\world")), (sys.path[0] + ("\Backups\ZipTempChace\world")))' instead of copyfile and now the only issue i have is it saves every directory along the way when i use 'shutil.make_archive("Backup1", 'zip', (sys.path[0]), (sys.path[0] + ("\Backups\ZipTempChace")))' like this [...](https://imgur.com/cpFbe4c) but i want it to save it like [this](https://imgur.com/iMdiEit)

Comment: I think you need to give the base path as as a relative to the root path, this means removing sys.path[0] in the 4th parameter